# AKS Azure Internal Loadbalancer

Tags: azure-aks

I'm working on a new AKS project - this is a POC for now. but I'm trying to understand what is best when delivering a production cluster.

I want to use AKS with an Azure Internal Loadbalancer and then use Traefik as my ingress controller. Regardless of the controller, I assume this the best practice for routing traffic to the front end rather than exposing the controller directly?

I have setup AKS with ACR and the internal load balancer, but for some reason, the backend pools contain all the nodes of each node pool in 1 backend pool. regardless if the pool of nodes is meant for different services - this doesn't seem right or is it that the controller will run on all nodes within all pools? therefor I just route the traffic to the controller?

Hope this makes sense, I'm sure this will lead to more questions, but for now, this will help me with the design.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the design behind this. All of the nodes might contain the pods for your service. So there is no way load balancer knows which nodes have the service and which dont. Do to prevent constant add\remove nodes from the backend, it just assigns all the nodes to the backend pool

Comment: Thanks for the reply, seems a bit of a design flaw. If you create multiple node pools, say web nodes, app nodes, and backend nodes. You wouldn't want all of those nodes assigned to a single backend pool of a load balancer. You'd want the traffic to arrive at the frontend pool which would be running the ingress controller and that would then route to the relevant nodes. Similar to how Service Fabric works. I definitely wouldn't want traffic on 443 from public internet arriving at any of the nodes in any pool. Or am i just miss-understanding how AKS works?

Comment: you are misunderstanding how kubernetes works. this is the design behind kubernetes, all the nodes listen to requests on the port you've chosen (or the random port chosen for you). if there are no pods on the node that receives the request - it will get forwarded to the node where the pod(s) reside. has nothing to do with AKS. load balancer behind SF would also target all the nodes in the backend. you cannot really target SOME of the nodes in a VMSS, so I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: In service fabric, you can specify which node types (all nodes in a particular VMSS) be fronted by the load balancer. So, for instance, I have an SF cluster made up of 3 VMSS (Web, App, Data) I only have the frontend VMSS in the load balancer - Then all requests from pubic internet will only ever arrive at the frontend node, the proxy running on the frontend nodes then uses the discovery service to route the traffic to the desired microservice. In AKS you can design a similar setup using node pools, but all nodes pools are assigned to the load balancer backend pool.